# How to share assembly info in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, assemblyinfo

I'm developing a REST Api using ASP.NET Core. I used to shared assembly info across my solution using a shared file containing common attributes such as AssemblyCompany, AssemblyCopyright, AssemblyTrademark and AssemblyVersion. In this way all of my projects in a solution would be compiled with the same Assembly info attributes.

In ASP.NET Core these attributes are now defined in the project.json file. Is there a way to share these attributes in a similar way?

Comment: I'm a bit behind the times and only just encountering this now, and it is SO ANNOYING. The shared AssemblyInfo.cs approach was elegant and easy. Very frustrating that it changed to such a clumsy way of doing it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception of AssemblyVersion, the assembly attributes you mentioned can still be defined in a shared file. This file can be added to the project under "buildOptions".

Example:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "compile": "../shared/AssemblyInfo.cs"
  }
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#buildoptions for more details.

AssemblyVersion can't be shared because it is always generated from the `"version"` value in *project.json*. `"version"` defaults to 1.0.0 if not specified.

Other attributes, such as AssemblyCopyright, will not be generated if their corresponding field is left empty in *project.json*.

Comment: Fails after VS2017 with the new msbuild based project types that does not make use of project.json And adding a linked file as we always have been able to do, does not work as a AssemblyInfo file is generated at compile time using meta data provided in the project.

Comment: Checkout this answer for some details on assembly info in csproj. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42183749/2526265

Answer (score 9):

In case others get by here and are looking for a solution that works with .Net Core > 2.1 and the new .csproj project files:

After some research I got it working using `Directory.Build.props` file in a parent directory. You can find the sample code and some more information [in this repository](https://github.com/mduu/dotnetcore_shared_assemblyinfo).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!