# Multi-target with .NET Compact Framework 3.5 using new .csproj format?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj, .net-cf-3.5

Is there a way to target .NET Compact Framework 3.5 with the new `.csproj` file format? I want to be able to target the following frameworks:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard1.0;net45;net40;net35;net35-cf</TargetFrameworks>
```

What I've done so far is based on this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/skarllot/4953ddb6e23d8a6f0816029c4155997a) - in detail, I've done the following:

1. Installed .NET CF 3.5 and Power Toys
2. Replaced `$(MSBuildBinPath)` with `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` in file `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets`
3. Copied all files from

   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE` to
   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\CompactFramework`
4. Created file `RedistList\FrameworkList.xml` in the above folder with the following contents:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FileList  Redist="Net35-CF" Name=".NET Compact Framework 3.5">
   </FileList>`
5. Added registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=CompactFramework` (just key, no value)
6. Created new project, set `TargetFrameworks` and added conditional property groups for `net35-cf`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net35-cf'">
    <!-- inference fails for this TFM, so specify it by hand -->
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETFramework</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>CompactFramework</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <!-- define compilation constants by hand too -->
    <DefineConstants>NET35_CF;WindowsCE</DefineConstants>
    <!-- disable implicit references, these are specified by hand, below -->
    <DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>True</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net35-cf' ">
    <NoStdLib>True</NoStdLib>
    <NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <PlatformID>E2BECB1F-8C8C-41ba-B736-9BE7D946A398</PlatformID>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net35-cf' ">
    <Reference Include="mscorlib, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac" />
    <Reference Include="System, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, when I try to compile my code, I get the following error message:

[image: net35-cf error with new csproj]

It seems that the general compilation is working, but the `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`is not part of the compact framework?

*Update 1*: when the `net35-cf` TFM is removed, the project compiles just fine.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Well, does it compile if you remove that?

Comment: Yes, it does. Will update the question with this info.

Comment: So... what's the question here? Just remove that attribute and be done with it

Comment: The question is: how can I target .NET Compact Framework 3.5 with the new csproj format, just as the title and the first sentence of the question states. If I remove the `net35-cf` TFM, then I do not target this specific framework.

Comment: Oh, you got me wrong, sorry. I meant "does it compile if you remove the `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`?"

Comment: I can't really remove that as the code is always re-generated via msbuild. I suspect that I did not configure msbuild properly - but I don't know where I should look to find the answer.

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable generation of `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` and `AssemblyVersionAttribute` by specifying so in the `.csproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup "'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net35-cf'">
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Reference: [Equivalent to AssemblyInfo in dotnet core/csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42138418)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - applying `<GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>` did the trick for me.