# Nuget Catch 22 after migrating VB project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am migrating a VB project from VS 2010 to VS 2017 and I am getting the following errors:

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: System.ArgumentException: '$(NETStandardImplicitPackageVersion)' is not a valid version string.
**StackTrace**
```

and

```
'C:\Users\PathToProject\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

I can get around the first error by turning off nuget restore as mentioned [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4706) but then i can't get past the second error, which requires nuget restore, or some other way to generate project.assets.json

Here is my vbproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{E3DC9794-BE3D-43DC-8198-8843B1A65546}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject>_GLENAIR_EEPROM_CONFIG_GUI.My.MyApplication</StartupObject>
    <RootNamespace>_GLENAIR_EEPROM_CONFIG_GUI</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Glenair EEPROM Config Interface</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <MyType>WindowsForms</MyType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ProductName>Glenair EEPROM Config GUI</ProductName>
    <PublisherName>Glenair</PublisherName>
    <SuiteName>Glenair EEPROM</SuiteName>
    <ApplicationRevision>4</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>2.4.0.4</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <CreateDesktopShortcut>true</CreateDesktopShortcut>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>Glenair EEPROM Config Interface.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
    <RemoveIntegerChecks>true</RemoveIntegerChecks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>Glenair EEPROM Config Interface.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
    <RemoveIntegerChecks>true</RemoveIntegerChecks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionExplicit>On</OptionExplicit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionCompare>Binary</OptionCompare>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionStrict>Off</OptionStrict>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionInfer>On</OptionInfer>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>AD3083285EA99B2F1F52BD898477B62BC6D3A802</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestKeyFile>990-05010-X_EEPROM_LOADER_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest>My Project\app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>GLENAIR_BERT_GUI.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetZone>LocalIntranet</TargetZone>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
    <EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems>false</EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Management" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Import Include="System.Linq" />
    <Import Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ApplicationEvents.vb" />
    <Compile Include="Form1.vb">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.vb</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" />
    <Compile Include="My Project\Application.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Application.myapp</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\Settings.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Settings.vb" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.vb</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="My Project\app.manifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="My Project\Application.myapp">
      <Generator>MyApplicationCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Application.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <None Include="My Project\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <CustomToolNamespace>My</CustomToolNamespace>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="GLENAIR_BERT_GUI.ico" />
    <Content Include="GLENAIR_BERT_GUI2.ico" />
    <None Include="Resources\9_inch_300_dpi_cmyk_logo.jpg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PublishFile Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <Group>
      </Group>
      <TargetPath>
      </TargetPath>
      <PublishState>Include</PublishState>
      <IncludeHash>True</IncludeHash>
      <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
    </PublishFile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Detailed Build Log: [Here](https://pastebin.com/rc9LL2EA) (Too long to post here)

Comment: Can you make a dummy project with the requisite NuGet packages and copy the generated project.assets.json (with any appropriate path etc. changes) to the real project?

Comment: Or, David Kean tantalisingly suggests that a `<ProjectFramework>` property might need to be present towards the end of the thread [another nuget error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159294/another-nuget-error.html).

Comment: Wrote an answer based on the wrong project system hint. If it doesn't help, please include the csproj content in the question to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Note that WinForms projects aren't really supported in the SDK/project-system, I'd be interested in how far you can get it to work. Also, you can remove the VB targets import since the SDK already does that.

Comment: Also, why are you using the web sdk? ( `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` ) since it is not a web application, you should remove the `.Web`

Comment: What you are trying to do is highly experimental at best.. if you want stable tooling you should use a normal migration by opening the old project file in VS 2017 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the csproj from the solution and add it again. Make sure you have a recent version of VS 2017 (at the time of writing 15.7.2).

This can happen if you migrate to an sdk-style project (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`) which is loaded using the classic csproj project system instead of the new project system specifically designed for this type of project.

The GUIDs in the solution as well as the ocurrance of a `<TargetFramework>` property determine which project system is used to load the csproj.

Comment: thanks, this got me passed the nuget errors but now im getting a bunch of compilation errors that looks like im missing some sort of SDK reference: http://prntscr.com/jmm8m6. i added vbproj and build log to original question

Comment: That's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138418/equivalent-to-assemblyinfo-in-dotnet-core-csproj