# how do you set Parallelizable Attribute in dotnet core for Nunit tests?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

A convenient way of running tests in parallel in nunit when in a dotnet framework project was to set this in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

> [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]

however in .net core or .net standard, there is no longer an AssemblyInfo.cs file.  So how can one set the scope to parallel in net core or net standard in just one place, without having to add that decorator on every single test class file?

Comment: You can put an assembly attribute in any file outside the namespace. It doesn't have to be in `AssemblyInfo.cs`, you could add your own `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. That said I have no idea if NUnit will recognize it in your .Net Core project.

Comment: @JSteward - you're right, you should post that as an answer! And NUnit supports Parallelizable in .NET Core 2.1, but not 1.1.

Comment: @JSteward thank you for your response.  How exactly would you do that?  If I were to just create an AssemblyInfo.cs file with the above attribute how would I tell my project to know to read it in?  would you do it like outlined here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138418/equivalent-to-assemblyinfo-in-dotnet-core-csproj/42183749#42183749

Answer (score 13):

Create WhateverNameYouWant.cs file.
Just put your code - NUnit will recognize it.

```
  using NUnit.Framework;
  [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this has to be outside of a namespace/class/struct/interface block, too.

Comment: How do you choose the number of tests you want running at the same time?
[assembly:LevelOfParallelism(3)] 
Can i just do this anywhere ?