# Assembly information not found in C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking to change my assembly and file version like this [image]

However, in my new project this does not appear [image]

I also tried to add it directly to the AssemblyInfo.cs file but it created a duplicate error.
[image]

Comment: It is visible in your screenshot, click Package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core projects don't support this dialog anymore. Edit your project file instead.

If you want to add your own assembly attributes, check this already answered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183749/7972419

Comment: Thank's for your answer, you help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

The `AssemblyInfo.cs` is not included in the default templates anymore because SDK-style project type supports setting this kind of information within the `csproj` file.

You have a couple of options for doing this:

1. You could set the `Version` property of your assembly within your project file . For example:

   netcoreapp3.0
        1.2.3
2. Another option is to set it during the build process - `dotnet build /p:Version=1.2.3`.